# PHP - Custom sort function improvement

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting, optimization

I first looked for some premade sort functions of PHP. I did find some, http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php , however this didn't support my needs. I not only wanted to sort ascending but also descending if possible. I couldn't find a function for this (I really apologize if I missed it. I find it hard to believe there is no such premade function, but couldn't find it)


I simply want a sort function that sorts a array by the given key. This should include letters and numbers. For this i used [strnatcasecmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcasecmp.php) and this worked perfectly. 
 

My function has 3 parameters: one for the array to sort, one for if it should be ascending or descending and one for the key that should be sorted on. 
Here is an example for an array that i use :

```
Array
(
    [test'l(ol.txt] => Array
        (
            [name] => test'l(ol
            [date] => 1379595716
            [size] => 0 b
            [extension] => txt
            [path] => shared\test/test'l(ol.txt
            [thumb] => images/files/txt.png
        )

    [test(2).txt] => Array
        (
            [name] => test(2)
            [date] => 1379595716
            [size] => 0 b
            [extension] => txt
            [path] => shared\test/test(2).txt
            [thumb] => images/files/txt.png
        )

    [test2.txt] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [date] => 1379595716
            [size] => 0 b
            [extension] => txt
            [path] => shared\test/test2.txt
            [thumb] => images/files/txt.png
        )

)
```

**My function :**

```
function sorteer($aNamen, $bAsc, $sAction)
{
    foreach($aNamen as $array)
    {
            $keyNaams[] = $array[$sAction];
    }

    //$for = '$i=0;$i < count($aNamen); $i++';
    $iStart = 0;
    $iEnd = count($keyNaams);
    $iPlus = 1;

    if($bAsc == true)
    {
        //$for = '$i=count($aNamen)-1;$i > 0; $i--';
        $iStart = count($keyNaams)-1;
        $iEnd = 0;
        $iPlus = -1;

        echo " <style type='text/css'>
                ." .$sAction. "
                {
                    -webkit-transform:scaleY(-1) !important;
                }
                </style>";
    }


    for($x=0;$x < count($keyNaams)*count($keyNaams); $x++)
    {
        //for($i = $iStart;$i .$forPar2. $evalPar3;$i. $forPar4)
        for($i=$iStart;$i != $iEnd; $i += $iPlus)
        {
            if(!empty($keyNaams[$i + $iPlus]))
            {
                if(strnatcasecmp($keyNaams[$i], $keyNaams[$i + $iPlus]) > 0) //string 1 groter dan string 2
                {
                    //echo $keyNaams[$i] .' is groter dan '. $keyNaams[$i - 1];
                    $nameTemp = $keyNaams[$i];
                    $keyNaams[$i] = $keyNaams[$i + $iPlus];
                    $keyNaams[$i + $iPlus] = $nameTemp;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    foreach($keyNaams as $name)
    {
        foreach($aNamen as $array)
        {
            if($array[$sAction] == $name)
            {
                $values = array_values($array);
                $key = array_keys($array);
                $i = 0;
                //$mapsSort = array();
                foreach($values as $test)
                {
                    if(!isset($mapsSort[$array['name']]))
                    {
                        $mapsSort[$array['name']] = array(
                                $key[$i] => $values[$i]
                        );
                    }

                    $arr = array(
                            $key[$i] => $values[$i]
                    );

                    $mapsSort[$array['name']] = array_merge($mapsSort[$array['name']], $arr);

                    $i = $i + 1;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return $mapsSort;
}
```

It first sorts the keynaams and use the sorted keynames to get the other propeties of the array. It will return the array of all file propeties.
 **Question :**

Now the problem is that it is really slow when you have a big array. It sometimes takes 10 seconds to load. Now i wonder if it is possible to make this function somewhat faster?
 I tryed to make the function as dynamic as possible.

 I hope i explained my thoughts of the function well enough. I really hope someone has some tips to improve this function. 
Really appreciate any help, Nkmol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uasort and implement a custom function, which sorts by the give parameter.

Comment: Doesn't uasort only supports ascending?

Comment: it sorts in that way your user functions specifies it. the compare function is build yourself and you decide when to return a 1 or -1.

Comment: Thank you sir! I should read the manual next time some more. Used this example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php#100279 
It's does generate really fast, thanks! :)